# Keeping a Maven/jetty app running permanently on GCE

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, jetty, google-compute-engine

I have created a VM instance on Google Cloud Ploutform, Compute engine. Installed Ubunutu 18.04 LTS, Java JDK, Maven and Jetty. Also installed Tomcat, but not using that at the mo.

I set the JAVA_HOME to the JDK location and added it to /etc/enviroment and confirmed this with source /etc/enviroment. Then I CD into my app run mnv jetty:run and the app comes up on port 8888 and everything works great.

Im using the GCE Browser SSH terminal and I have two problems. When I close my laptop or shut the browser the app terminates and goes down. So I have to SSH back into GCE and run the above command but firstly it tells me that my java home is pointing to jre not JDK. Running echo JAVA_HOME shows its correct, so I need to run source /etc/environment before mvn jetty:run each time I log in.

1, How do I make the app stay open so its not reliant on a open terminal on my PC (happy to leave one open and running on the machine just not sure how to do this).

2, Why do I have to run a source each time I log in? Surely having it set in the environment file is enough?

Im a bit of a newb on java and linux so any help/advice appreciated.

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can run your app in the background so that even if you close the
   terminal it will not affect the java process. You can use this
   command

   $ nohup mvn jetty:run &

You logs will be redirected to a file called nohup.out in the same directory

2. For setting the env variables there is one file called /etc/profile.
   Just mention the details in this file and login/logout, it will be
   permanent.

Comment: excellent thank you I will look into this. Once started how do I stop it then should I want to?

Comment: You can get the pid of the process using “ps auxw | grep mvn”. Just kill that pid to stop the process using “kill -9 <pid>”

Comment: Second column would be the pid